# Stomp over sockjs angular 5 client with spring boot backend randomly disconnects once per lifecycle

Tags: angular, spring-boot, websocket, stomp, sockjs

I have an angular 5 client connecting to a spring boot backend using sockjs + stomp. It is working fine, except that once per "client connection lifecycle" the client randomly (after about 20-30 seconds) looses the socket connection to the backend. After another call to the connect(..) function inside the error callback, the socket connection stays up for the rest of the runtime.

The behaviour is the same on both the newest version of Chrome and Firefox.

The angular client has the following dependencies for the stomp and socketjs:

```
"sockjs": "^0.3.19",
"stompjs": "^2.3.3",
```

This is how the connection is managed on the client side:

```
private sockAddress: string = '/websocket';
private socket;
private stompClient;
private subscriptions: [string, (message: String) => void][];
...
connect() {
    const headers = {};
    this.socket = new SockJS(this.sockAddress);
    this.stompClient = Stomp.over(this.socket);
    this.stompClient.heartbeat.incoming = 1000;
    this.stompClient.heartbeat.outgoing = 1000;
    this.stompClient.connect(headers, this.connectCallback.bind(this), this.errorCallback.bind(this));
  }

connectCallback(frame): void {
    // called back after the client is connected and authenticated to the STOMP server
    this.isConnected = true;

    for (let subscription of this.subscriptions) {
      this.subscribeToEndpoint(subscription[0], subscription[1]);
    }
  }

errorCallback(): void {
    console.log('error callback called, socket not connected!');
    this.isConnected = false;
    // reconnecting
    this.connect();
  }

sendMessage(message: string, endpoint: string): void {
    if (this.stompClient != null && this.isConnected) {
      this.stompClient.send(endpoint, {}, message);
    } else {
      console.log('socket not connected');
    }
  }

private subscribeToEndpoint(endpoint: string, callback: (message: String) => void) {
    if (this.isConnected == true) {
      this.stompClient.subscribe(endpoint, callback);
    }
  }
```

This is the relevant server side part for the configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        ThreadPoolTaskScheduler te = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
        te.setPoolSize(2);
        te.setThreadNamePrefix("wss-heartbeat-thread-");
        te.initialize();
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/data").setTaskScheduler(te).setHeartbeatValue(new long[]{1000, 1000});
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry stompEndpointRegistry) {
        stompEndpointRegistry.addEndpoint("/websocket").withSockJS();
    }
}
```

And how messages are handled:

```
@MessageMapping("/element/create")
@SendTo("/data/element/created")
public ApprovedElementDTO createElement(CreateElementDTO element) {
    LOG.debug("createElement called: " + element.getType().toString());
    return this.socketService.approveElementId(element);
}
```

The relevant maven dependency used for the socket:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

The error message on the client looks as follows:

```
zone.js:2933 POST http://localhost:4200/websocket/461/1uzrn1r4/xhr_send?    t=1513249327232 404 (Not Found)
scheduleTask @ zone.js:2933
ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:411
onScheduleTask @ zone.js:301
ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:405
Zone.scheduleTask @ zone.js:236
Zone.scheduleMacroTask @ zone.js:259
(anonymous) @ zone.js:2966
proto.(anonymous function) @ zone.js:1366
AbstractXHRObject._start @ abstract-xhr.js:132
(anonymous) @ abstract-xhr.js:21
ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:425
onInvokeTask @ core.js:4621
ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:424
Zone.runTask @ zone.js:192
ZoneTask.invokeTask @ zone.js:499
ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:488
timer @ zone.js:2040
setTimeout (async)
scheduleTask @ zone.js:2056
ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:411
onScheduleTask @ zone.js:301
ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:405
Zone.scheduleTask @ zone.js:236
Zone.scheduleMacroTask @ zone.js:259
(anonymous) @ zone.js:2072
proto.(anonymous function) @ zone.js:1366
AbstractXHRObject @ abstract-xhr.js:20
XHRCorsObject @ xhr-cors.js:8
(anonymous) @ ajax-based.js:21
BufferedSender.sendSchedule @ buffered-sender.js:59
BufferedSender.send @ buffered-sender.js:26
SockJS.send @ main.js:163
Client._transmit @ stomp.js:159
Client.send @ stomp.js:366
SocketService.sendMessage @ socket.service.ts:79
ElementTransmission.sendElementCreationEvent @ ElementTransmission.ts:56
PluginHandler.sendElementCreationEvent @ PluginHandler.ts:266
DiagramComponent.onClick @ diagram.component.ts:150
dispatch @ scripts.bundle.js:4
q.handle @ scripts.bundle.js:4
ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:425
onInvokeTask @ core.js:4621
ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:424
Zone.runTask @ zone.js:192
ZoneTask.invokeTask @ zone.js:499
invokeTask @ zone.js:1540
globalZoneAwareCallback @ zone.js:1566
stomp.js:134 Whoops! Lost connection to http://localhost:4200/websocket
```

Sometimes I also get randomly this error message but without any affect on the connection:

```
VM3454:164 WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:4200/websocket/954/i52geoxw/websocket' failed: Connection closed before receiving a handshake response
WrappedWebSocket @ VM3454:164
WebSocketBrowserDriver @ websocket.js:6
WebSocketTransport @ websocket.js:32
SockJS._connect @ main.js:219
SockJS._receiveInfo @ main.js:193
g @ emitter.js:30
EventEmitter.emit @ emitter.js:50
(anonymous) @ info-receiver.js:67
g @ emitter.js:30
EventEmitter.emit @ emitter.js:50
(anonymous) @ info-ajax.js:37
g @ emitter.js:30
EventEmitter.emit @ emitter.js:50
xhr.onreadystatechange @ abstract-xhr.js:124
wrapFn @ zone.js:1166
ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:425
onInvokeTask @ core.js:4621
ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:424
Zone.runTask @ zone.js:192
ZoneTask.invokeTask @ zone.js:499
invokeTask @ zone.js:1540
globalZoneAwareCallback @ zone.js:1566
```

On the Spring boot backend I get the following Exception when the connection loss happens, which is the same as when I terminate the client by simply closing the browser tab.

```
2017-12-14 12:02:09.507  INFO 16672 --- [tboundChannel-6] o.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor   : An error occurred in processing while on a non-container thread. The connection will be closed immediately

java.io.IOException: Eine bestehende Verbindung wurde softwaregesteuert
durch den Hostcomputer abgebrochen
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:51) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:65) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:471) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel.write(NioChannel.java:134) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioBlockingSelector.write(NioBlockingSelector.java:101) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.write(NioSelectorPool.java:157) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.doWrite(NioEndpoint.java:1221) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.flushBlocking(SocketWrapperBase.java:451) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.flush(SocketWrapperBase.java:441) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11OutputBuffer.flushBuffer(Http11OutputBuffer.java:514) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11OutputBuffer.flush(Http11OutputBuffer.java:243) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.flush(Http11Processor.java:1495) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessor.action(AbstractProcessor.java:284) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.coyote.Response.action(Response.java:167) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.doFlush(OutputBuffer.java:336) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.flush(OutputBuffer.java:303) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.flushBuffer(Response.java:541) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.flushBuffer(ResponseFacade.java:312) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.flushBuffer(ServletResponseWrapper.java:176) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.flushBuffer(ServletResponseWrapper.java:176) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.util.OnCommittedResponseWrapper.flushBuffer(OnCommittedResponseWrapper.java:158) [spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.flushBuffer(ServletResponseWrapper.java:176) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.util.OnCommittedResponseWrapper.flushBuffer(OnCommittedResponseWrapper.java:158) [spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.server.ServletServerHttpResponse.flush(ServletServerHttpResponse.java:96) [spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.session.AbstractHttpSockJsSession.writeFrameInternal(AbstractHttpSockJsSession.java:350) [spring-websocket-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.session.AbstractSockJsSession.writeFrame(AbstractSockJsSession.java:322) [spring-websocket-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.session.StreamingSockJsSession.flushCache(StreamingSockJsSession.java:86) [spring-websocket-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.session.AbstractHttpSockJsSession.sendMessageInternal(AbstractHttpSockJsSession.java:290) [spring-websocket-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.session.AbstractSockJsSession.sendMessage(AbstractSockJsSession.java:166) [spring-websocket-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.handler.ConcurrentWebSocketSessionDecorator.tryFlushMessageBuffer(ConcurrentWebSocketSessionDecorator.java:132) [spring-websocket-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.handler.ConcurrentWebSocketSessionDecorator.sendMessage(ConcurrentWebSocketSessionDecorator.java:104) [spring-websocket-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.messaging.StompSubProtocolHandler.sendToClient(StompSubProtocolHandler.java:439) [spring-websocket-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.messaging.StompSubProtocolHandler.handleMessageToClient(StompSubProtocolHandler.java:426) [spring-websocket-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.messaging.SubProtocolWebSocketHandler.handleMessage(SubProtocolWebSocketHandler.java:338) [spring-websocket-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.support.ExecutorSubscribableChannel$SendTask.run(ExecutorSubscribableChannel.java:135) [spring-messaging-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_152]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_152]
    at java.lang.Thread.run

(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_152]
```

Do you have any suggestions what might be wrong in my code, which causes these connection drops?
This is a serious problem for me because sending packets does of course not work during the reconnection time. Also the error callback is only called when I (or the heart-beat) tries to send a packet.

Comment: My websocket implementation also gets the same error. Found any clues or solution to this one?

Comment: Are you using the Proxy functioinality of Angular dev mode?
In my case this was the root of the problem, the proxy was not configured properly for websockets, the following entry in "proxy.conf.json" fixed it:  
"/websocket": {
    "target": "http://localhost:8080",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "warn",
    "ws": true
  }

where the 
"ws": true
part was missing.

Comment: Did you find the solution to this problem?

Comment: @rob_ yes I could solve the problem. See my comment above and also the now added answer (same content).

Answer (score 0):

In my case this was the root of the problem, the proxy was not configured properly for websockets, the following entry in `proxy.conf.json` fixed it: `"/websocket": { "target": "localhost:8080", "secure": false, "logLevel": "warn", "ws": true }` where the `"ws": true` part was missing.